# Notation question about $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1} $

Tags: general-topology

So I was looking reviewing the fundamental group in Topology by James Munkres and encountered this expression 
$f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1} $.

My question, assuming $\,f : G \to G'$, how can $x$ inverse exist if there doesn't exist a function, say $w$, like $w: T \to G$? Or should I just consider $f(x^{-1})$ to mean $f(x)^{-1}$ when I see it again in the book. I also thought about just letting $f$ consider $(x^{-1})$ as an ordinary input that only activates the inverse after the map occurs, but I know that does sound strange.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ is a group, so $x^{-1}$ denotes the group-theoretic inverse of $x$.